# Ensure both calls to database and SQS succeed

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, amazon-sqs

Basically what I'm trying to do is send data to both RDS MySQL database and a message to an SQS queue in the application layer and make sure both of them succeed.

The flow goes as follows: when a user requests an API a lambda function is called inserting data into the database and also sending a message to an SQS queue which another lambda functions pulls then sends the same data to elasticsearch. I'm using an SQS queue here to handle retries and so on.

To ensure this flow works I just need to make sure both calls to database and SQS succeed or else this whole thing fails. e.g. if database succeeds and the call to SQS queue failed the data won't make it to elasticsearch, so both of them should succeed or fail together.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a message is sent to an Amazon SQS queue, you can't "undo" it. Therefore, I would recommend:

- **Insert the data** into the database

  - If it failed, retry a few times
  - If all retries fail, then **exit** with a FAIL status
- **Send the message** to SQS

  - If it failed, retry a few times
  - If all retries fail, then **reverse the insertion into the database** and **exit** with a FAIL status
- Return a SUCCESS status

Comment: But if SQS is down everything fails even database, From a decoupling prespective is that a good thing to do?

Comment: If SQS fails, my suggestion is to reverse the insertion into the database as a "roll-back" mechanism. By the way, in the 10+ year history of AWS, I don't think you'll find that SQS has failed (at least, not on its own -- it might have failed if there was a region-wide problem). There might be network failures to reach AWS, but actual failures within AWS are amazingly rare.

Comment: From your experience, Do u think sending data to database and a message to SQS is better (which will eventually send the same data to elasticsearch) OR maybe send the data to the database then to elasticsearch directly and only if elasticsearch fails I'd then send it to SQS instead?